# Excel Variables

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have the following code:

```
 Sub Strukturkopieren()
 Dim TZahl As Integer
 Dim GZahl As Integer
 Dim MaxZahl As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim j2 As Integer
 Dim g As Integer
 Dim Startp As Integer
 Dim Startp2 As Integer

  MaxZahl = Worksheets("Control").Cells(2, 2).Value

  For i = 1 To 20

  j = 2 * i
  j2 = j - 1
  TZahl = Worksheets("Control").Cells(12, j).Value

  For g = 1 To TZahl

  Startp = GZahl * 2 + 1 + (g - 1) * 2
  Startp2 = Startp + 1

  Set varRangeselect1 = Worksheets("Control").Range(Cells(13, j2), Cells(2013, j))
  Set varRangeSelect2 = Worksheets("Structures").Range(Cells(2, Startp), Cells(2002, Startp2))
  varRangeselect1.Copy
  varRangeSelect2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

  Next g

  GZahl = TZahl + GZahl

  Next i



End Sub
```

I am trying to copy a set of structures a given amount of time (MaxZahl) to another sheet. VBA gives me a 1004 Error and points to line:

```
Set varRangeselect1 = Worksheets("Control").Range(Cells(13, j2), Cells(2013, j))
```

Did I declare a variable wrong?

Comment: Put the `Worksheets("Control"). ` in front of the `Cells`.  Like this `Worksheets("Control").Cells(13,j2),Worksheets("Control").Cells(2013,j)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using multiple worksheets, you should be explicit when using `Range() and Cells()`, so VB knows which worksheet to use.

So for your lines

```
 Set varRangeselect1 = Worksheets("Control").Range(Cells(13, j2), Cells(2013, j))
  Set varRangeSelect2 = Worksheets("Structures").Range(Cells(2, Startp), Cells(2002, Startp2))
```

You should do:

```
 Set varRangeselect1 = Worksheets("Control").Range(Worksheets("Control").Cells(13, j2), Worksheets("Control").Cells(2013, j))
  Set varRangeSelect2 = Worksheets("Structures").Range(Worksheets("Structures").Cells(2, Startp), Worksheets("Structures").Cells(2002, Startp2))
```

OR, use `With` (my personal preferred method, as it shortens the code a little):

```
With Worksheets("Control")
    Set varRangeselect1 = .Range(.Cells(13, j2), .Cells(2013, j))
End With
With Worksheets("Structures")
    Set varRangeSelect2 = .Range(.Cells(2, Startp), .Cells(2002, Startp2))
End With
```

(Note: When using `With`, you'll use just a period (`.`) before `Range()` and `Cells()`, as VB understands that to mean that you want to work with whatever is after `With`, in this case, `Worksheets("Control")` and `Worksheets("Structures")`.

How you have it now, VB sees that you want to use the Range in the "Control" and "Structures" worksheets, but when it tries to determine what `Cells` you're using, it's not sure what sheet you want...Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks alot to you and all the others, this helped me alot. Thanks alot to you all!